# Netbeans format JS code inside html tags

Tags: javascript, html, netbeans, formatting

**NetBeans** is not smart enough to format Javascript code inside HTML tags.

Is there any plugins or solutions for this?

I have only found [this link](https://github.com/drewhjava/netbeans-jsbeautify) but it only works on a `clean.js` file.

Only thing that comes on my mind is copying content to a js file formatting it and then past it back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any online tool to format your code as there is present a lot of tools to beautify it.

Here is [the one link](http://ctrlq.org/beautifier/). This tool is very nice as I have seen that you can use this tool to formatting any code like HTML, PHP, Javascript, or CSS as a time.

Hope this will be helpful to you.

Comment: So you have to copy your code, paste it in  a web form, copy it from there and paste it back into your local code editor? That's quite a cumbersome work flow for serious development...